# Does the sitemap.xml file does from the xmlsitemap module actually get generated?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I see that there is a 1.xml file generated in the sites/default/files/xmlsitemap folder, but I do not see a file in the Drupal root. However, when I call http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml I do get the info. Is this the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's normal behaviour.

[xmlsitemap_menu()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21xmlsitemap%21xmlsitemap.module/function/xmlsitemap_menu/7) includes a route for /sitemap.xml specifically.

Answer (score 1):

This is utterly normal behavior: the module caches the sitemap in the files directory, then delivers it via `http://www.example.com/?q=sitemap.xml` which gets mapped to `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml` with clean URLs.